# How to replace a string using regexp in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to filter a given string and replace some common words from a given string:

```
const str ='api/knwl/tests/products';
const str1 = 'api/users';
const str2 = 'api/tests/providers';
```

I want to filter the words 'api', 'knwl' or 'tests' from a given strings.

I tried somthing with regexp:

```
/(?!(tests|api|knwl))/g
```

But it doesn't work. How can I fix this issue? I'm not expert on regexp.

Comment: you want to get those words from string?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead so it's a 0-length match, it will match the first (or all because of g flag) position that is not followed by one of the three words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex - `/(tests|api|knwl)/g`;

```
const str ='api/knwl/tests/products';
const str1 = 'api/users';
const str2 = 'api/tests/providers';

const filterRegex = str.replace(/(tests|api|knwl)/g,''); // replace all occurence of strings (tests,api,knwl) to empty.
```